# Increment column value based on value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as below:

```py
       ID  Value  counter  
    0  A   30      3
    1  A   30      3
    2  A   30      3
    3  A   30      3
    4  A   30      3
    5  A   30      3
    6  B   50       2
    7  B   50       2
    8  B   50       2
    9  B   50       2
   10  C   40      2
   11  C   40      2
   12  C   40      2
   13  C   40      2
```

I want to add a new column `Value1`.  At every repetition of ID the value in column `Value` should be incremented and saved in column `Value1`. However, it should only be incremented by number given in column `Counter` then it should repeat. Below is the desired output.

```
   ID  Value  counter  Value1
0  A   30      3        31
1  A   30      3        32
2  A   30      3        33
3  A   30      3        31
4  A   30      3        32
5  A   30      3        33 
6  B   50      2        51
7  B   50      2        52
8  B   50      2        51
9  B   50      2        52
10  C   40      2        41
11  C   40      2        42
12  C   40      2        41
13  C   40      2        42
```

My attempt:

```
df['Value1'] = df['Value']
df['Value1'] += df.groupby('ID')['Value1'].cumcount() +1
```

But this does not consider the counter and just increments. How is it possible to repeat the increment after the counter value has reached.

Comment: Please post the input df as copy pasteable code

Comment: How `5` and `44` from first dataframe became `50`, and `40` respectively in the second one?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the modulo operator to reset your `.cumcount` by the value of `df["counter"]`

```
df["Value1"] = (
    df["Value"] + df.groupby("ID")["Value"].cumcount().mod(df["counter"]).add(1)
)

print(df)
   ID  Value  counter  Value1
0   A     30        3      31
1   A     30        3      32
2   A     30        3      33
3   A     30        3      31
4   A     30        3      32
5   A     30        3      33
6   B     50        2      51
7   B     50        2      52
8   B     50        2      51
9   B     50        2      52
10  C     40        2      41
11  C     40        2      42
12  C     40        2      41
13  C     40        2      42
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the `cumcount` is fine, assign it to a new column, then decrease the values of `cumcount` for the records where count is less than `cumcount`, finally add the value and `cumcount` and assign it to `value1`

```py
df['cumcount'] = df.groupby('ID')['Value'].cumcount() + 1
while(df['cumcount']>df['counter']).any():
    df.loc[df['cumcount'] > df['counter'], 'cumcount'] = df['cumcount'] - df['counter']

df['value1'] = df['Value'] + df['cumcount']
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   ID  Value  counter  cumcount  value1
0   A     30        3         1      31
1   A     30        3         2      32
2   A     30        3         3      33
3   A     30        3         1      31
4   A     30        3         2      32
5   A     30        3         3      33
6   B     50        2         1      51
7   B     50        2         2      52
8   B     50        2         1      51
9   B     50        2         2      52
10  C     40        2         1      41
11  C     40        2         2      42
12  C     40        2         1      41
13  C     40        2         2      42
```